# Search in txt file, sum +1 and write the file

Tags: php, find, save, sum

Good day guys,

I am really nowhere to the guy who do PHP coding, so I am asking you.

I have file in txt format and in that file somewhere I am having line with "count: (n)", where "(n)" can be any numeric value.

I need to search for count: (n), take the (n) value, sum it with +1 and save the file again.

So if I will have count: 10 it must be 10 + 1 = 11.

Thank you!

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: what does `line with count: (n).` means? Line number? Sting `count 2` or what? Maybe you need to simply count number of lines in file? )

Comment: that mean that somewhere in the file will be ONE line which contains "count: (n)" where (n) can be any numeric value what I need to find. It's a standard abbreviator for this kind of things. Did you even went to school at all? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use some regex to parse the 'count: n' string from the file. Although my regex is kind of rusty, this pattern might help:

```
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'r+'); // Open the file for reading and writing into the variable $file.
$fileContents = file_get_contents($file); // Load the contents of the file to variable $fileContents.

$countString = preg_match('/count: [0-9]+/', $fileContents); // Find instances of string 'count: n' where n is an integer, load the string into $countString.
$count = preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $countString); // Find the integer from $countString, load into $count.
$count++; // Iterate count up one.

$newCountString = 'count: '.$count; // The 'count: n+1' string where n is the original integer.

$newFileContents = preg_replace('/count: [0-9]+/', $newCountString, $fileContents); // Find the string 'count: n' and replace with 'count: n+1' where n is the original integer.
fwrite($file, $newFileContents); // Write the new contents into the file.
fclose($file);
```

Good luck!

Comment: `preg_match`ing file contents rules!